# Using pivot_longer with multiple column classes

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a dataset that has this structure (lots of questions asked to survey respondents) that I want to reshape from wide to long:

```
library(tidyverse)
df_wide <-
  tribble(
    ~resp_id, ~question_1_info, ~question_1_answer, ~question_2_info, ~question_2_answer,
    1, "What is your eye color?", 1, "What is your hair color?", 2,
    2, "Are you over 6 ft tall?", 1, "", NA,
    3, "What is your hair color?", 0, "Are you under 40?", 1
  )
```

This is the output I would like:

```
df_long <- 
  tribble(
    ~resp_id, ~question_number, ~question_text, ~question_answer,
    1, 1, "What is your eye color?", 1,
    1, 2, "What is your hair color?", 2,
    
    2, 1, "Are you over 6 ft tall?", 1,
    2, 2, "", NA,
    
    3, 1, "What is your hair color?", 0,
    3, 2, "Are you under 40?", 1
  )
```

I'm having problems getting the multiple classes of the columns to work together. Here's what I've tried:

```
  df_wide %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = !resp_id,
    names_to = c("question_number"),
    names_prefix = "question_",
    values_to = c("question_text", "question_answer")
  )
```

I can't get the right configuration of `names_to` or `names_prefix` and `values_to`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `names_pattern` after rearranging the substring in column names

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df_wide %>%
  # rename the columns by rearranging the digits at the end 
  # "_(\\d+)(_.*)" - captures the digits (\\d+) after the _
  # and the rest of the characters (_.*) 
  # replace with the backreference (\\2, \\1) of captured groups rearranged   
  rename_with(~ str_replace(., "_(\\d+)(_.*)", "\\2_\\1"), -resp_id) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -resp_id, names_to = c( ".value", "question_number"), 
        names_pattern = "(.*)_(\\d+$)")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  resp_id question_number question_info              question_answer
    <dbl> <chr>           <chr>                                <dbl>
1       1 1               "What is your eye color?"                1
2       1 2               "What is your hair color?"               2
3       2 1               "Are you over 6 ft tall?"                1
4       2 2               ""                                      NA
5       3 1               "What is your hair color?"               0
6       3 2               "Are you under 40?"                      1
```